# Magento 2: How to validate cart price rule in product view?

Tags: magento2, cart, blocks, rules

I'm trying to show the price rules in the product view, but I can not find a way to validate if a product meets the rule...

At the moment I just get all the rules.

**Block:**

```
class RuleDescription extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    protected $_registry;
    protected $_collection;
    protected $_rule;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule\CollectionFactory $collection,
        \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule $rule
    )
    {
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        $this->_collection = $collection;
        $this->_rule = $rule;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getCurrentProduct()
    {
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
    }

    private function getAllCartRules()
    {
        return $this->_collection->create();
    }

    public function getActiveCartRules()
    {
        $product = $this->getCurrentProduct();

        /**
         * get cart price rule
         */

        $rules = $this->getAllCartRules()->toArray();
    }
}
```

I know it's not easy because of the amount of conditions, but is there any way?